# KDESvn 'Add ssh-identities to ssh-agent' doesnt work

Tags: svn, ssh

i generated a pair of keys. i want kdesvn to remember it but when i click on 'Add ssh-identities 
to ssh-agent' it does **nothing**!
i tried `ssh-add id_dsa` (id_dsa is my private key) but i guess it has nothing to do with the kdesvn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparantly it has nothing to do with the svn client, i had to set the permissions on ssh folder and its contents like this (on host): `chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*`